# The type or namespace name 'Decoder' does not exist in the namespace 'FluxJpeg.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

what does this error mean?

```
The type or namespace name 'Decoder' does not exist in the namespace 'FluxJpeg.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

And how to handle it?

Comment: You probably didn't include whichever dll defines the `FluxJpeg.Core` namespace or `Decoder` is defined in a different dll.

Comment: It means that you don't nearly told us enough about what kind of project you are trying to use it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed missing an assembly, right click on `Decoder`, `Resolve`, using `whatever it proposes`.

`whatever it proposes` is usually like `System.something`. If it is just that, a quick tour on Google would have been sufficient.

Else you are trying to use something that doesn't exist. Checking for typos may can solve the problem.

If `Decoder` comes from another .dll, take a look in `References` in your `Solution Explorer`, and make sure the .dll is referenced.